# Creating a web.config by code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a social networking site, and would like users to be able to upload videos and photos to share. Uploaded files would be stored in a personal directory, accessible only to the user and his/her friends.

To limit access, I was considering creating a web.config file for each upload. So far, I haven't found a way to create and update a web.config file by code (for example, when a user accepts a friend request, the new friend must be added to the web.config file).

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can create web.config files by code?

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want to deal with user uploaded content in this way. There are a few reasons:

1. Allowing users to upload content which is physically stored in the application directory could expose you to a major security risk.
2. Each time you update the Web.config the application pool would recycle making your application unusable.
3. As your social network scales you would need to distribute load across multiple servers at which point storing data on the local servers vs. some kind of centralised or distributed cache would be unworkable.

I recommend that you provide a facility for users to upload content which then stores that content in some kind of blob storage mechanism (databases, cloud service providers all have these). From there you can either funnel the data back out through your application code when a particular URL is requested or, if you blob storage provider supports access controls you could generate a key that allows direct download from blob storage. The nice thing about that is that you can often flick a switch and get popular content CDN enabled.

Good luck with your social network!